# Two 3-dimensional side by side plots with gridspec - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot two three-dimensional figures side by side with the gridspec package.

Consider the following example

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

G = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 2)

ax1 = plt.subplot(G[0:2, 0])
#ax1 = plt.axes(projection="3d")
#ax1.plot3D([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3])


ax2 = plt.subplot(G[0:2, 1])
#ax2 = plt.axes(projection="3d")
#ax2.plot3D([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3])
```

which creates

[image]

By removing the route signs one gets 3D plots. But for some reason there is only one 3D plot

[image]

What went wrong and how do i get 3d figures side by side with gridspec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `G`, and then you re-create the axes. If you use `add_subplot` with the grid `G`, you can see both 3D plots in the same figure.

```
fig = plt.figure()
G = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 2)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(G[0:2,0], projection='3d')
ax1.plot3D([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(G[0:2,1], projection='3d')
ax2.plot3D([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3])

plt.show()
```

Result is below.
[image]